# Views block that shows all references to current node (cross references)

Tags: views, 9

I'm confused with views filters and relations...

In my articles I have a field (field_article_reference_nodes) that references other nodes and shows these as a link.
Now I want to attach a view to other nodes that lists all articles referencing them.

So this is kind of a cross reference.
How do I have to set the filters/relations for this view to list all articles that are referencing the current node?

Thanks for your support!
Mathias

Comment: That's called reverse entity reference and you want to get the referencing entities. Maybe have a look at https://www.drupal.org/project/reverse_entity_reference

Comment: Thanks @leymannx, sounds perfect but doesn't support Drupal 9.x yet.
Is there a custom way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After knowing that this approach is called "reverse entity reference".
I found this tutorial:
https://mushtaq.ch/blog/4/drupal-8-reverse-entity-reference-in-view

But in step 3 I needed to use "Content USING field_myfield" instead of "Content referenced from field_myfield".

Thanks for your help!